# Spring-ws apache Camel with soap version 1.2

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws

I am working with spring-ws apache camel which by default supports soap 1.1. But I want to post a request binding it to soap 1.2 as my endpoint service supports only soap 1.2. I tried setting up the messageFactory like the below in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">               <property name="soapVersion">                   
<util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>               
</property>                        
</bean>
```

then added it to RouteBuilder like,
.to("spring-ws:https://"+url+"?soapAction=#xxx&wsAddressingAction=#xxx&messageFactory=#soapMessageFactory

But it doesn't work. Is there any other way to set the soap version in spring-ws component ? I don't have access to the Webservice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar situation and took a slightly different approach to solve the issue. I created a custom WebServiceTemplate and attached my message factory to it.  Then I specified the webServiceTemplate as part of the call in the RouteBuilder.  Here is the code:

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
    final MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
    final SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(msgFactory);
    final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(messageFactory);

    return webServiceTemplate;
}
```

And then in my route, I made the call like this:

```
    .toD("spring-ws:{{some.service.url}}?webServiceTemplate=#webServiceTemplate&wsAddressingAction=http://test.org/SomeService/SomeOperation")
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the above and it still doesn't work for me. I am getting the below exception,                                                                      
AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present
at org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper

Comment: This was the same issue that I was facing with messageFactory. May be the endpoint service expects some other property header? As I don't have access to the webservice and also the requests are not being logged anywhere in the service, finding it hard to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Are you setting the wsAddressingAction as part of the spring-ws call?  I found a different thread that talked about disabling WS-A in order to get rid of the error message you're seeing.  Perhaps just try using the webServiceTemplate without the wsAddressingAction to see if that helps.  Sounds like you don't have access to this service, so I'm assuming you aren't able to call it through SoapUI to see a successful raw response?  If you were able to, then you'd be able to kick up the spring logging and compare the generated request to a successful one.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for the response.I did try without wsAddressingAction but that did not work either and I am getting the same Addressing property exception. 
When I don't add the webservicetemplate and add the wsAddressingAction, I get the soapfault error on the incompatible soap version. Not sure if webservicetemplate suppresses the addressing property or my endpoint service expects some other property in the request. I used the spring logging and I could see the headers and the body but not the envelope. I assume the envelope gets wrapped before sending the request and cannot be logged?

Comment: You should be able to see the envelope as well.  See this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/common.html#logging). There are a couple things you can do to increase the camel logging too if you haven't tried them yet.  In your route, you can do `getContext().setTracing(true)` at the beginning of the method to see more details about the route.  Right before the spring-ws call, you can do a `.to("log:test?showAll=true")` to see the current body.  Between those three things, I'd think you'd get the majority of the logging you need.